# get request in keycloak rest api

Tags: rest, api, get, request, keycloak

Firstly I have a json like:

```
[
{
    "id": "123",
    "createdTimestamp": 1491814115926,
    "username": "p111",
    "enabled": false,
    "totp": false,
    "emailVerified": false,
    "attributes": {
      "piid": [
        "1212"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I want to write a get request that retrieve user. 
My url that get all users is like:

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/master/users
```

and I can filter according to username:

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/master/users?username=p111
```

but I want to filter according to `piid`. How can I do this?
An help is appreciated.

Comment: Not natively: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-1902 but you can add a custom endpoint https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2017-February/009548.html